# 1-wire fairy lights

Tags: lighting

I have here some fairly lights. It's a string of coloured LEDs with a transformer and control box at one end. The control box lets you select a bazillion different lighting patterns. (Presumably the box contains a small microcontroller. I suspect it uses PWM to dim the LEDs.)

There are 4 colours of LED, but they always light in pairs. This leads me to believe they're wired as two independent circuits. Presumably wiring each colour individually would use twice as much wire, which would eat into the manufacturer's precious profit margins.

This got me thinking... Is there some way you could connect *all* the LEDs to a *single* circuit yet still be able to control them independently? In particular, I'm wondering if you would connect each LED across the power rails in series with some sort of trivial passive band-pass filter. That way, the microcontroller can generate some complex multi-band waveform, but each LED only receives a narrow(ish) frequency band to light it.

Basically, I'm wondering if something similar to this could be made to work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsjZwu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where each colour of LED has a band-pass filter tuned to a different frequency. (I gather capacity on its own isn't really a functioning filter...)

To be clear, I doubt this would end up actually being any cheaper to manufacture. But I'm wondering if it's technically *possible*. (I'm also not intending to try to *make* it, just figure out what the schematic would look like.)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, but there is a pretty common way of driving multiple LEDs using time multiplexing, It is based on the fact that human eye can't distinguish the flickering if it is frequent enough.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Doesn't that still require multiple connections though? It avoids 1 wire per LED, but it's still more than 1 total, right?

Comment: It will never be 1 wire, as even most basic circuit will require 2. But you can put a "receiver" circuit to drive *each* LED an use some kind of 1-2 wire bus protocol (+power) to control these. That will be expensive, though

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right. When I said "1 wire", I guess I meant "1 circuit"...

Comment: You could have individually addressable LEDs, and the signals to each superimposed on the power line, that would get you to two wires.

Comment: If the ground for the LEDs was common with the power supply and you didn't mind using a wall socket at each end of the string of LEDs, could you not get away with just 1 wire?

Answer (score 4):

One wire, are you sure? "Addressable" LEDs are becoming rather common and this might be what you are describing. This is where each "LED" includes a red, green, and blue LED inside, along with a serial interface. This uses four wires typically. The serial data piped into one LED is "daisy-chained" to the next, all the way to the end of the array. This data transfer typically happens very fast - hundreds of times per second, so isn't noticeable except for very long runs. The end result is "each LED can be a different color and they all can change in any way imaginable," depending on how "smart" the controller is.

In terms of datasheets, here is a 5mm [WS2812](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/WS2812.pdf) addressable LED module:
[image: WS2812 LED]

Answer (score 2):

**For two LEDs, on two wires**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvL7dH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With LEDs attached as above, you can illuminate the red ones by applying a voltage in one direction, and the green ones by applying a voltage the other way. Just make sure you choose LEDs with which can safely withstand a reverse voltage sufficient to light the other type. If the LEDs have different forward voltages (and they probably will) you'll need series resistors on each one, or you'll need a current drive rather than a voltage.

If you want both on, switch back and forwards too fast for the eye to see.

You can even get a single IC containing the transistors necessary to switch the voltage on and off, backwards and forwards. It's called a H-Bridge, and they are typically used to control DC motors.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as I had the same idea a few years ago I'll answer.

The basic idea is that each LED has a filter tuned to a different frequency range. To light any combination of LEDs you send the matching frequencies.

When I had the idea, I drew a simple LC filter and graphed the frequency response for a selection of component values. What I found was that the frequency response for each filter was not very sharp, and there was significant overlap even with the capacitor values spaced one decade apart. I concluded that for more a handful of channels some of the capacitors would be awkwardly large. Perhaps the non-linear response of the LEDs would mitigate this somewhat. I'd need to build it!

I can't find the files I made, but I think my proposed circuit would've looked something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY1h8F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is that each capacitor and inductor pair form a band-block filter that shorts out the LEDs at frequencies outside the relevant band. The resistor would be replaced with a constant current sink.